# How to listen that a user created by firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword has been written to the firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a user with createUserWithEmailAndPassword and it saves the user to real-time firebase database. After I create the user, I want to update this user data in the database.

The usual flow is the that createUserWithEmailAndPassword creates a user and saves it to the database, and after that I update that user's data.

However, sometimes the user is created but not saved in the database by createUserWithEmailAndPassword , the updates are set firstly, then the createUserWithEmailAndPassword saves the user to the database so it overrides the updates.

By the way, I use async await to wait for the promise returned by createUserWithEmailAndPassword to resolve and then start updating the user.

```
const res = await secondaryApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, password)
await secondaryApp.auth().signOut();

if (newAvatar) {
  const type = newAvatar.type.slice(6);

  const { blob } = newAvatar;

  const ref = storage.child(`users/${res.user.uid}.${type}`);
  const image = await ref.put(blob);
  const imageUrl = await image.ref.getDownloadURL();

  user.avatar = imageUrl;
  user.thumbnail = imageUrl;
}

await firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`users/${res.user.uid}`).set(
    {
      public: {
        ...user
      }
    }
  ).then(
    firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(user.email).then(
      done(
        "success",
        "Successfull user creation.",
        `A new user has been created.`
      )
    )
  )
```

},

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) as shown in the documentation to register for a callback when a user is signed in, no matter how they managed to get signed in.  You can use this callback to make sure the user's records are created, if necessary.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
  }
});
```

The observer is invoked both when a new user has been created, or just signed in with an existing account.  In both cases, you will need to check your database to make sure your database has the correct information.

Comment: Actually I am creating user from the admin panel, so I do not need them to sign in, I just want tot create them and update there data. I attached the code to the question, you can check it and get what I mean. Thank you by the way.

Comment: The code you're showing creates the user account in the app.  If you have a different situation, then edit the question to explain what you are actually doing.